# Android WebView/XWalkView blank under In-App Payment dialog

Tags: android, webview, in-app-billing, crosswalk-runtime

My problem is quite simple. I have a WebView (XWalkView actually) that is showing fine, then I'm triggering in app billing call that shows Google Play's payment dialog.

The thing is, when the dialog pops up, the webview appears blank although I am expecting to stay still in background of the dialog.

And the funny thing is that webview's content comes back when the dialog is close. Also, I noticed that the remote debugger says the following "The tab is inactive" (I guess this is related)

What am I missing to keep my webview in background during payment process?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Crosswalk to be animatable. You'll have to run this before any XWalkViews are created.

```
XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.ANIMATABLE_XWALK_VIEW, true);
```